# How to predict a discrete dependent variable on a continuous scale using regression

Tags: machine-learning, regression, predictive-modeling, linear-regression

I am trying to find the 'optimal' amount of a certain medicinal cream to be applied to a patient in order to minimize the days the patient has a rash. However, the data for the cream doses are of the values 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, and 1 (on some scale, e.g., 50 milliliters). I am trying to build a regression model using these discrete values and find the optimal value on a continuous scale (i.e. outside these discrete values, [the optimal amount of cream to be applied could be 0.37]). I would also like to be able to predict the number of days a patient has a rash based on a continuous medicinal cream dose input (e.g., if a dose of 0.65 was applied, the patient would have a rash for 4 days)

At present, I am performing regression analysis suitable for continuous dependent variables e.g. lasso regression. Then using the model I have built, I am predicting the number of days a patient has a rash for, using a continuous input to 2 decimal places [0,0.01, 0.02, .... 0.98, 0.99, 1] a large number of times to see which consistently produces the lowest number of rash days.

I am unsure if this is the right approach any confirmation/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the "dose" $y$ is limited to $y \in [0,1]$. So in the moment you have "bunching" in your target value $y$ which you try to remove. In this case, a linear regression could lead to "overshooting" ([see here for more details](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/75253/71442)). So it could be beneficial to use some estimator which "restrics" $\hat{y} \in [0,1]$ as well.

This can be achieved using "beta regression". Here is an [R implementation](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/75253/71442), where the docs say:

> Fit beta regression models for rates and proportions via maximum
> likelihood using a parametrization with mean (depending through a link
> function on the covariates) and precision parameter (called phi).

Example:

```
library("betareg")
data("GasolineYield", package = "betareg")
summary(GasolineYield$yield)

Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
0.0280  0.1165  0.1780  0.1966  0.2705  0.4570 

br = betareg(yield ~ batch + temp, data = GasolineYield)
preds = predict(br, newdata=GasolineYield)
summary(preds)

Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
0.04571 0.10309 0.16364 0.19655 0.26429 0.50792
```

The second problem you mention "*predicting the number of days...*" is not clear to me in the moment. In case the second model is independent from the first one, the approach might be well suited as a sanity check or alternatively to get some high level estimate. However, I guess to test your model in some sence, you would need to look into [bootstraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)) or likely less complicated: [cross validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)).

Comment: With regards to the second problem, the ultimate goal is to try and build a model that given a dose value between 0 and 1 (to lets say 2 decimal places) can predict the number of days the patient will have a rash for. So do you think it is best to use beta regression and dose as the y variable and then take the inverse of the model to predict the number of days given an inputted dose value (e.g. 0.36)?